# No component factory found for NgbModalBackdrop. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? even i add enteryComponent to my module

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am creating an angular module other than the app module and adding an enterycomponent "ManageLocationComponent" in it but it still shows the same error in the console heres my code

```
 `@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, AngularMaterialModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [AdminManageLocationComponent, ManageLocationComponent],
  exports: [AdminManageLocationComponent, ManageLocationComponent],
  entryComponents: [ManageLocationComponent]
  })`
```

Any Help

Answer (score 2):

If you still are having this issue I fixed it when I had it by adding `NgbModule` to my imports array in NgModule. Also yes you will also need the entryComponents which it looks like you already have.

Comment: is there any other way? It makes the module havier to load. (It loads the whole module...... which is more than 100 kB in gzipped state!)

Comment: Importing the `NgbModalModule` is sufficient in this case. No need to load the entire `NgbModule`.

Comment: * I had declared and and added component in both declaration and entrycomponents of ngModule . But still error occurs.

* By importing NgbModule from ng-bootstrap fixed the issue. 

Angular 8

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem i solve it with the following steps

1- import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

2- in NgModule imports add NgbModule.

thank.